# T-SQL NULL-Friendly Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a table "tblSalesOrder" in Microsoft T-SQL with some sample records:

```
SalesOrderID    OrderDate    ItemID    Quantity   PromotionCode
====================================================================
1               2014-09-01   100       5          NULL
2               2014-09-01   120       10         ABC
3               2014-09-05   150       7          NULL
4               2014-09-08   200       15         NULL
```

I need to return NULL-friendly resultset for records which do not exist.

As an example, I want a monthly query for September 2014:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, ItemID, Quantity, PromotionCode
FROM tblSalesOrder
WHERE OrderDate = BETWEEN '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-30'
```

I need it to return at least 1 row for each day (i.e. 0 valued row, if the entry for that day is not available)

```
SalesOrderID    OrderDate    ItemID    Quantity   PromotionCode
====================================================================
1               2014-09-01   100       5          NULL
2               2014-09-01   120       10         ABC
0               2014-09-02   0         0          0
0               2014-09-03   0         0          0
0               2014-09-04   0         0          0
3               2014-09-05   150       7          NULL
0               2014-09-06   0         0          0
0               2014-09-07   0         0          0
4               2014-09-08   200       15         NULL
0               2014-09-09   0         0          0
    ...
    ...
    ...
0               2014-09-30   0         0          0
```

Comment: Why do you need it? Can't you code it on the program you are building?

Comment: **Why** do you need it to do this? You should handle this in your presentation layer e.g. report, webpage, form, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` the a date parameter in an empty `select` and `coalesce` the values:

```
select coalesce(t.SalesOrderID, 0) SalesOrderID
,      coalesce(t.OrderDate, d.OrderDate) OrderDate
,      coalesce(t.ItemID, 0) ItemID
,      coalesce(t.Quantity, 0) Quantity
,      coalesce(t.PromotionCode, 0) PromotionCode
from   (select @dateParameter OrderDate) d
left
outer
join   ( SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, ItemID, Quantity, PromotionCode
         FROM tblSalesOrder
       ) t
on     t.OrderDate = d.OrderDate
```

Comment: I don't see how this would ever work. select @dateParameter OrderDate will return 1 row. So the number or rows this will return is the number of rows from tblSalesOrder (or 1 if empty). Also another minor bug

Comment: That was the question: one line if no lines from the original table.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I think I got your point. The original question was changed a lot after my answer.

Comment: Been there tried that, hard to make a dynamic solution that changes with the question.

Answer (score 2):

master..spt_values is a table in all microsoft sql databases containing 2506 rows, by cross joining, it will have 2506*2506 rows to calculate dates between from and to. Other tables can be used as well, this is just a table used to create the dates. A calendar table would be even easier to use.

The EXCEPT will remove all dates already in use. Then by combining the rows from tblSalesOrder and CTE with union all, empty days will be filled with the required hardcoded values:

```
DECLARE @from date = '2014-09-01'
DECLARE @to date   = '2014-09-30'

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT top (case when @to < @from then 0 else datediff(day, @from, @to) + 1 end)
    dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) - 1, @from) OrderDate
  FROM 
    master..spt_values t1
  CROSS JOIN 
    master..spt_values t2
  EXCEPT
  SELECT 
    OrderDate
  FROM 
    tblSalesOrder
)
SELECT 
  0 SalesOrderID, OrderDate, 0 ItemID, 0 Quantity, '0' PromotionCode
FROM
  CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT
  SalesOrderID, OrderDate, ItemID, Quantity, PromotionCode
FROM
  tblSalesOrder
ORDER BY
  OrderDate, SalesOrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @startDate date= '20140901'
    ,@endDate date = '20140930';

WITH Calendar as (
    SELECT @startDate as OrderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, OrderDate) as OrderDate
    FROM Calendar
    WHERE OrderDate < @endDate
)

SELECT coalesce(t.SalesOrderID, 0) SalesOrderID
,      coalesce(t.OrderDate, Calendar.OrderDate) OrderDate
,      coalesce(t.ItemID, 0) ItemID
,      coalesce(t.Quantity, 0) Quantity
,      CASE WHEN t.OrderDate IS NULL THEN  '0' ELSE t.PromotionCode END as PromotionCode    FROM Calendar
    LEFT JOIN tblSalesOrder t ON Calendar.OrderDate = t.OrderDate
ORDER BY Calendar.OrderDate, t.SalesOrderID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: your idea is pretty good, however there are 2 bugs and one overflow issue in your code. Find them and I will upvote

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Fixed, thanks for noticing. It's your turn to fix your code :)

Comment: haha, refered to my test table. That will teach me to throw bricks. Hint: Try your code for an entire year

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Sure "OPTION". My turn :) Your PromotionCode will never be NULL. And say a few words about rights access to the master database. Not everyone have it

Comment: Opened the posibility for new issues in my script by changing it a bit. Hopefully I didn't miss anything